# How to add temporary css for a single test in qUnit?

Tags: javascript, css, testing, qunit

I have a component under test that behaves differently based on a current css of the site. I would like to add a css for a single test. Is it possible to add it without creating a file, like a temporary css for the test only?

Is it possible to add a css code in the qUnit test function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) node dynamically with desired CSS rule.

```js
var tempCSS = document.createElement("style");
tempCSS.type = "text/css";
tempCSS.innerHTML = ".myClass { background-color: red; }";
document.body.appendChild(tempCSS);
```

```html
<div class="myClass">yahoooooooo</div>
```